# How to check status of a non-registered task?

Tags: celery

My application A calls a celery task *longtask* in application B. However, *longtask* is registered in B but not in A, so A calls it by using `send_task`. I want a mechanism in A to check periodically if *longtask* is complete. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send_task` returns an `AsyncResult` that contains the task id.  You can use this id to periodically check on the result of *longtask*.

```
result = my_app.send_task('longtask', kwargs={})
task_id = result.id

# anywhere else in your code you can reuse the 
# task_id to check the status
from celery.result import AsyncResult
import time

done = False
while not done:
    result = AsyncResult(task_id)
    current_status = result.status
    if current_status == 'SUCCESS':
        print('yay! we are done')
        done = True
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: `AsyncResult(task_id)` was the part i was looking for; worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Without going into details, I must add that my_app.AsyncResult(task_id) is a more complete answer than AsyncResult(task_id)